# Equivalent of $in in mongo c# driver 2.0

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using c# driver 2.0 for mongo db. How do I get a list of documents from the database using the $in clause. I couldnt find anything equivalent in the driver documentation.

E.g. To get one album

```
Album alb =  _collection
            .Find(x => x.ImageId == 1)
            .ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I would like to get multiple albums in one query. (something like this)

```
List<Album> albs =  _collection
                .Find(x => x.ImageId "IN (pass in a list of ids)" )
                .ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can do it with Linq. Have you explored the options LinQ offers...?

Comment: I read that driver 2.0 does not support LinQ yet.

Answer (score 3):

```
// IMongoCollection<Album> _collection = ...
var fdb = Builders<Album>.Filter;
var filterIn = fdb.In(x=>x.ImageId, new[] { /*id list*/ });
_collection.Find(filterIn).ToList();
```